# altering query in db2 to fix count from a join

Tags: sql, db2

I'm getting an aggregated count of records for orders and I'm getting the expected count on this basic query:

```
SELECT
    count(*) as sales_180,
    180/count(*) as velocity

FROM custgroup g

WHERE g.cstnoc = 10617
    AND g.framec = 4847
    AND g.covr1c = 1763
    AND g.colr1c = 29
    AND date(substr(g.extd1d,1,4)||'-'||substr(g.EXTD1d,5,2)||'-'||substr(g.EXTD1d,7,2) ) between current_Date - 180 DAY AND current_Date
```

But as soon as I add back in my joins and joined values then my count goes from 1 (which it should be) to over 200. All I need from these joins is the customer ID and the manager number. so even if my count is high, I'm basically just trying to say "for this cstnoc, give me the slsupr and xlsno"

How can I perform this below query without affecting the count? I only want my count (sales_180 and velocity) coming from the custgroup table based on my where clause, but I then just want one value of the xcstno and xslsno based on the cstnoc.

```
SELECT
    count(*) as sales_180,
    180/count(*) as velocity,
    c.xslsno as CustID,
    cr.slsupr as Manager

FROM custgroup g
    inner join customers c
        on g.cstnoc = c.xcstno
    inner join managers cr
        on c.xslsno = cr.xslsno

WHERE g.cstnoc = 10617
    AND g.framec = 4847
    AND g.covr1c = 1763
    AND g.colr1c = 29
    AND date(substr(g.extd1d,1,4)||'-'||substr(g.EXTD1d,5,2)||'-'||substr(g.EXTD1d,7,2) ) between current_Date - 180 DAY AND current_Date
    GROUP BY c.xslsno, cr.slsupr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are producing multiple rows when joining, so your count is now counting all the resulting rows with all that [unintended] multiplicity.

The solution? Use a table expression to pre-compute your count, and then you can join it to the other tables, as in:

```
select
    g2.sales_180,
    g2.velocity,
    c.xslsno as CustID,
    cr.slsupr as Manager
  from customers c
  join managers cr on c.xslsno = cr.xslsno
  join ( -- here the Table Expression starts
SELECT
    count(*) as sales_180,
    180/count(*) as velocity
FROM custgroup g
WHERE g.cstnoc = 10617
    AND g.framec = 4847
    AND g.covr1c = 1763
    AND g.colr1c = 29
    AND date(substr(g.extd1d,1,4)||'-'||substr(g.EXTD1d,5,2)
        ||'-'||substr(g.EXTD1d,7,2) ) 
        between current_Date - 180 DAY AND current_Date
  ) g2 on g2.cstnoc = c.xcstno
```

You can also use a Common Table Expression (CTE) that will produce the same result:

```
with g2 as (        
  SELECT
      count(*) as sales_180,
      180/count(*) as velocity
  FROM custgroup g
  WHERE g.cstnoc = 10617
    AND g.framec = 4847
    AND g.covr1c = 1763
    AND g.colr1c = 29
    AND date(substr(g.extd1d,1,4)||'-'||substr(g.EXTD1d,5,2)
        ||'-'||substr(g.EXTD1d,7,2) ) 
        between current_Date - 180 DAY AND current_Date
  )
select
    g2.sales_180,
    g2.velocity,
    c.xslsno as CustID,
    cr.slsupr as Manager
  from customers c
  join managers cr on c.xslsno = cr.xslsno
  join g2 on g2.cstnoc = c.xcstno
```

Comment: Thank you, trying to do your first option I get the error "Column CSTNOC not in table G2 in *N."

Comment: THen, maybe you cannot pre-compute this result, and this answer is not valid. Why are you grouping by CSTNOC?

Comment: I'm not, I'm grouping by c.xslsno, cr.slsupr because they are not a part of the count, simply static values. So the CSTNOC is being used in the WHERE clause for the count, and then I just want one instance of the SLSUPR and XSLSNO per that customer

Comment: So the count and velocity are based on the where clause. I just want the xslsno and slsupr that are assigned for that cstnoc